# How to retrieve a url parameter from request in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-request

I want to perform certain operations with a model in a middleware. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $itemId = $request->param('item'); // <-- invalid code, serves for illustration purposes only
    $item   = Item::find($itemId);

    if($item->isBad()) return redirect(route('dont_worry'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

My question is, how can I retrieve the desired parameter from the `$request`?

Comment: "request->param('item') "   Do you mean request GET/POST parameter?

Comment: @pbwned just a url parameter. For example extract the `id` part from `/item/{id}` route

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $itemId = $request->item;
    //..............

}
```

Answer (score 13):

If the parameter is part of a URL and this code is being used in Middleware, you can access the parameter by it's name from the route given:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $itemId = $request->route()->getParameter('item');
    $item   = Item::find($itemId);

    if($item->isBad()) return redirect(route('dont_worry'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

This is based on having a route like: `'/getItem/{item}'`

Comment: I got the error: 'getParameter()' method does not exist. I got the parameters like this: `$request->route()->parameters['item']`

Comment: Me too. `$request->route('item')` works for me. Laravel 5.7

Comment: $request->route()->parameters['item'] and $request->route('item') both works for laravel 5.5 too. but 'getParameter()'  does not

Answer (score 3):

> Use this after Laravel 5.5

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $item = Item::find($request->route()->parameter('item'));
    if($item->isBad()) return redirect(route('dont_worry'));
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, we can use the below method also to get the parameter,

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $itemId = $request->query('item');

}
```