# get the attributes from a post request on a Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, post, request

I have a route that is meant to be a post request, and within the controller I want to know what values I send in the post request, I'm new to Laravel. How can I do this?

This is the code for my model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OMeta extends Model
{
    protected $fillable= ['n_bandera','h_entrada','h_salida','locacion','fecha','ticket','so'];
}
```

And I want to get the `'n_bandera'` attribute from the post request. How could I do it in the following controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    // get the 'n_bandera' attribute from the $request

}
```

Also, I don't want to use methods like `all()` since I want the content from the request to go to different tables in a database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve a url parameter from request in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38741084/how-to-retrieve-a-url-parameter-from-request-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you have to retrieve form data in a controller method from different way:

if your form field name is n_bandera then the controller method should like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function store(Request $request){
  $n_bandera = $request->get('n_bandera'); //use get method in request object 
  OR 
 $n_bandera = $request->input('n_bandera'); //use input method in request object
  OR 
 $n_bandera = $request->n_bandera;   //use dynamic property 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    /* your form needs to have an input field name as n_bandera*/
    $n_bandera = $request->n_bandera;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request){
     $requestData = $request->all();
     $n_bandera = $requestData['n_bandera'];

  /* your form input field name */


}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //get the 'n_bandera' attribute from the $request
    $n_bandera = $request->get('n_bandera');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *$request->all()*, for that purpose you can use *request->only()* , like that:

```
ModelOne::create($request->only('model_one_param_one'));
ModelTwo::create($request->only('model_two_param_one','model_two_param_two));
```